# How to calculate the number of prime numbers in a group of numbers?

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

If two different numbers are randomly selected from seven integers from 2 to 8, what is the probability of the two numbers being mutually prime?

Take 2 different numbers randomly from 7 integers from 2 to 8, and there are 21 different methods
If the two numbers are not mutually prime, the different methods are:(2,4),(2,6),(2,8),(3,6),(4,6),(4,8),(6,8) 7 in total,

So the probability is

```
p = (21 - 7)/21
```

How to use mathematica to calculate the classical probability problem including prime number and coprime problem?

Comment: I saw your other related question and added explanations and various links to my answer. Hopefully, this explains the logic. Also, check the answer by @Syed :-)

Comment: The title and body of the post ask two different questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edited version:**

**Explanation:**

We begin by creating a list of numbers in the appropriate range. This we can achieve very easily, using [**`Range`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html?v=13.2) in the following manner:

```
range = Range[2, 8];
```

Then, we wish to derive the 21 different combinations of the numbers that we have above. We can use [**`Tuples`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html?v=13.2) to get all possible tuples of length 2 from the list above. In that result, we can combine [**`DeleteDuplicatesBy`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html?v=13.2) and [**`Sort`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html?v=13.2) to delete sublists that contain the same elements. In that we employ [**`Cases`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html?v=13.2) to enforce the condition that the sublists, also, don't have two equal elements. So, it looks like this:

```
Cases[Tuples[range, 2] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Sort] &, {x_, y_} /; 
  x != y]
```

Following the suggestion by @Bob Hanlon in the comments, we can re-write in a much cleaner way as:

```
Subsets[range, {2}]
```

Either `Subsets` or `the long combo` will give the list of the 21 combinations.

> [image: Blockquote]

So, now you are at a position to [**`MapApply`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html?v=13.2) a question about numbers being relatively primes using [**`CoprimeQ`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoprimeQ.html?v=13.2) in the following way:

```
CoprimeQ @@@ (Cases[
   Tuples[range, 2] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Sort] &, {x_, y_} /; 
    x != y])
```

> [image: Blockquote]

And now we are almost done. All that needs to be done, is to choose the non-relatively prime numbers, i.e the `False` statements of the list, and then take the [**`Length`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html?v=13.2) of the lists you have created to get your number.

The command in the original answer is:

```
(1/Length[
    CoprimeQ @@@ (Cases[
       Tuples[range, 2] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Sort] &, {x_, y_} /; 
        x != y])]) (Length[
    CoprimeQ @@@ (Cases[
       Tuples[range, 2] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Sort] &, {x_, y_} /; 
        x != y])] - 
   Length[Cases[
     CoprimeQ @@@ (Cases[
        Tuples[range, 2] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Sort] &, {x_, y_} /;
          x != y]), False]])
```

which, of course, using the hint in the comments section, gets significantly shorter

```
(1/Length[CoprimeQ @@@ (Subsets[range, {2}])]) (Length[
    CoprimeQ @@@ (Subsets[range, {2}])] - 
   Length[Cases[CoprimeQ @@@ (Subsets[range, {2}]), False]])
```

Both of the above give you

[image: res]

Comment: `Cases[Tuples[range, 2] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Sort] &, {x_, y_}  /;  x != y]` can be shortened to `Subsets[range, {2}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks for this. I will update in a bit as soon as I finish something :-)

Comment: @bmf,```Subsets[range, {2}]```Through this, we can know how the specific 21 combinations are. But what function can we know that there are 21 arrays after listing them?

Comment: @csn899 sorry, but I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Let me explain further. If you just do `Subsets[Range[2, 8], {2}]` you will get the explicit combinations. If you `Subsets[Range[2, 8], {2}] // Length` you will get an answer `21` which tells you how many there are. If you change the `Range` you get different answers.

Comment: ```CoprimeQ @@ # &```What does this mean in this command?

Comment: @csn899 I think I am being blind to something. Where did I use this command?

Comment: @csn899 anyway, you have to take a look at [**`@@`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) which is `Apply`. I already told you what `CoprimeQ` does.

Comment: @csn899 you are, also, looking for [**`#`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) which is called `Slot`. These are stuff that you can find directly from your notebook

Comment: What is the method to extract and list the two numbers that are mutually prime and not mutually prime. Instead of listing true and false judgments

Comment: @csn899 what you simply call `True` and `False` statements is **PRECISELY** mathematica telling you that numbers are mutually prime or not mutually prime. That is, when you insert two numbers. This is it. If you want to **generate** those numbers, i.e consider a number say `2` generate a relative prime or generate a relative non-prime is completely different as a question

Answer (score 9):

Incorporating @BobHanlon 's comment:

```
(Count[#, True]/Length@#) &@ (CoprimeQ @@@ Subsets[Range[2, 8], {2}])
```

> 2/3

Answer (score 2):

```
coprime = 
 GroupBy[Subsets[{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {2}], CoprimeQ @@ # &, 
  Length]
First@coprime/Total@coprime
```

Update:

```
coprime = GroupBy[Subsets[Range[2, 8], {2}], CoprimeQ @@ # &, Length]
First@coprime/Total@coprime
```

Method two:

```
list = Subsets[Range[2, 8], {2}]
coprimelist = Select[list, GCD @@ # == 1 &]
Length[coprimelist]/Length[list]
```

[image]